# Vmstat Output Squashed

Tags: solaris-10

I'm working on determining if one of our servers is running out of memory. We are using Solaris 10 for our OS. One of the most recommended commands to help diagnose memory issues is vmstat. The examples I've seen of this command look like.

```
$ vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0 305416 260688  29160 2356920    2    2     4     1    0    0  6  1 92  2  0
```

I wish my output looked that nice, but when I run the utility, the output looks like:

```
root@db01:# vmstat
 kthr      memory            page            disk          faults      cpu
 r b w   swap  free  re  mf pi po fr de sr m1 m2 m3 m4   in   sy   cs us sy id
 0 0 0 5070952 10237720 848 483 5240 105 103 0 0 11 20 5 0 4659 13472 4951 3 1 96
```

Now, IDK about you experts, but I cannot tell the difference between the free and re column, nor the po and fr columns. Can I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `vmstat` without options is pretty useless.  Per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1462/vmstat-1m.html): *Without options, `vmstat` displays a one-line summary of the virtual memory activity since the system was booted.*  A "summary ... since the system was booted" is pretty useless for determining exactly what's happening *now*.  As for which column is which?  Count 'em.